# Using a subquery to get a COUNT from a different table in Django

Tags: django, subquery

I have these models:

```
class IceCream(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Topping(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ice_cream = models.ForeignKey(IceCream, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="toppings")
    is_active = models.BooleanField(db_index=True)
```

I would like to run the following query to get a list of all ice creams, together with a count of the total number of available toppings, which in SQL would look like this:

```
SELECT ice_cream.*, 
   (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM topping WHERE topping.ice_cream = ice_cream.id AND topping.is_active = True) AS total_toppings
FROM ice_cream
```

This is a simplified version and there are more parameters in there, but if I can make this work, then things should work out. Can I do this in Django using [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) expressions? I have not managed to make it work. Or are raw queries my only way out here because of the COUNT that I want to include in the subquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `annotate` for this, which supports aggregation functions like `Count`. You can also add filters to aggregation functions by providing a `Q` object.

```py
# ...
from django.db.models import Count, Q
# ...

qs = IceCream.objects.all().annotate(
    active_toppings_count=Count("toppings", filter=Q(toppings__is_active=True))
)

for ice_cream in qs:
    print(ice_cream.name, ice_cream.active_toppings_count)
```

This uses a Left (outer) join to produce the results. This is (likely) better for performance than using a subquery.

If you *must* use a subquery, you can do the following:

```py
from django.db.models import F, Func, OuterRef, Subquery
#...

subq = (
    Topping.objects.filter(is_active=True, ice_cream=OuterRef("pk"))
    .annotate(count=Func(F("id"), function="Count"))
    .values("count")
)
qs = IceCream.objects.annotate(active_toppings_count=Subquery(subq))
```

Then the resulting SQL is equivalent to your raw SQL example:

```sql
SELECT "myapp_icecream"."id",
       "myapp_icecream"."name",
       (SELECT Count(U0."id") AS "count"
        FROM   "myapp_topping" U0
        WHERE  ( U0."ice_cream_id" = ( "myapp_icecream"."id" )
                 AND U0."is_active" )) AS "active_toppings_count"
FROM   "myapp_icecream"
```

Comment: Thanks. However, this query creates a JOIN of the tables and I'm looking for a way to run a subquery (my code is more complex than above and there are reasons for this being needed... any way to get the SQL code from my example to run the same way in Django?)

Comment: @user74934 I've added an example that uses subquery specifically. Though, be advised it is probably less performant than the left outer join in the first example.

Answer (score 2):

The [django-sql-utils](https://github.com/martsberger/django-sql-utils) package makes this easy, `pip install django-sql-utils` and then

```py
from sql_util.utils import SubqueryCount

queryset = IceCream.objects.all().annotate(
    total_toppings=SubqueryCount('toppings', filter=Q(is_active=True))
)
```

Comment: Thanks that is very good to know! The first answer also covered the question even though the code is more complicated, but it uses regular Django code without additional packages, so I accepted that one but +1 for this package and much simpler syntax!